Most concise way of creating a WPF custom control as a composition of other existing controls
I need to create a new control which is composed of a TextBox and a Button. The most concise way I've found at the moment is with a CusomControl like this:

inherit from TextBox and add the functionality of the command that must happen with the Button
 public class MyTextBoxWithButton : TextBox
 {
     ...
     DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyTextBoxWithButton), new    FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyTextBoxWithButton)));
     ...

     public SomeBehaviourForTheButtonCommand(){...}
 }



in a ResourceDictionary, clone ALL the default TextBox template and replace the border with something like
    <DockPanel>
        <Border>
        <Button>
    </DockPanel>

the part I don't like is having cloned the ENTIRE TextBox default template.
I don't like the unnecessary duplication and also the additional work if in the future I want to add e.g. dark theme.
I can reduce the duplication a bit by extending the type style
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" TargetType="{x:Type local:MyTextBoxWithButton}">

With this I can avoid some initial property setters but the definition of the ControlTemplate remains entirely duplicated.
The other solution would be to implement a UserControl, but the cost of the boiler plate on the DependencyProperty seems equally high and ugly to me.
In general is there a way to create a control while minimizing code and xaml duplication?

Can you elaborate on why you would not use a UserControl?


"but the cost of the boiler plate on the DependencyProperty seems
equally high and ugly to me"

What high costs? And you can use code templates to let the IDE generate all the code for you. You only fill in the blanks like type and property name.
You extend a class when you want to add functionality. If you want to group controls and add functionality to that new group of controls then you don't extend the classes you want to group. Instead, you create a completely new control (e.g. extend Control or ContentControl). If you don't want to enable customization you could also create a UserControl.
MyControl.cs
public class MyControl : Control
{
  public static RoutedCommand SomeBehaviourForTheButtonCommand { get; }
    = new RoutedCommand(nameof(SomeBehaviourForTheButtonCommand), typeof(MyControl));

  static MyControl()
    => DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
      typeof(MyControl), 
      new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl)));

  public MyControl()
  {
    var commandBinding = new CommandBinding(SomeBehaviourForTheButtonCommand, ExecutedSomeBehaviourForTheButtonCommand, CanExecuteSomeBehaviourForTheButtonCommand);
    this.CommandBindings.Add(commandBinding);
  }

  private void ExecutedSomeBehaviourForTheButtonCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e) 
    => throw new NotImplementedException();

  private void CanExecuteSomeBehaviourForTheButtonCommand(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) 
    => e.CanExecute = true;
}

Generic.xaml
Here you can define the visuals of MyControl by composing it of other controls like a TextBox and a Button.
<Style TargetType="MyControl">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="MyControl">
        <Bortder>
          <Stackpanel>
            <TextBox />
            <Button Command="{x:Static MyControl.SomeBehaviourForTheButtonCommand}" />
          </Stackpanel>
        </Bortder>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

